# Mental health issues and success in academia. Is it possible to be successful after multiple blocks in the early academic career?

Tags: research-process, health

So, is it possible to be successful in academia or demanding research fields with Mental health issues? I don't read anecdotes of successful academics with mental health issues. This makes me believe that I could never make it. What do you think?

Comment: An extreme example of a successful academic with mental illness is John Nash, who won the Nobel prize for economics and had schizophrenia. Speaking personally, I too struggled with anxiety and low self-confidence during my PhD, as did many of my friends. It's normal and you're doing the right thing by seeking professional help.

Comment: I don't know but I think a supportive mentor could make the difference!

Comment: It's definitely possible and there certainly are people in academia suffering mental health issues (I did and know many who did). As others have said, you are doing the right thing by seeking professional help. If I could give a piece of advice it would be to be kind to yourself. You managed to successfully complete several publications and complete a PhD in only 6 years while beating mental health issues! It sounds like you are tenacious and talented; this will carry you far.

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/how-can-we-better-react-to-askers-who-are-having-a-mental-health-crisis

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into *Imposter Syndrom*, and you will see that severe self-doubts are no rarity amongst successful academics. You'll find discussion of coping strategies, etc.
2. My impression is that academia is a welcoming environment for a broad variety of mental health issues, provided you are on the high-functioning side. But opinions on this will vary.
3. Keep in mind that applying for academic positions and for grants almost always has abysmal success rates. This could be living hell for you, or the shock therapy that helps you overcome your paralyzing fear of failure.
4. The vast majority of recent PhD graduates contemplating a career in academia will not make it to a permanent faculty appointment. Numbers vary with discipline, but my extremely rough estimate would be that 1 out of 10 succeed. So with the extremely limited information I have about you, I would have to guess that you wouldn't make it to professor -- because that is my default guess, not because of mental health issues.
5. To get a better idea of what your personal chances are, discuss this with a trusted mentor who knows you, your track record and the job market in your academic niche. Also, contemplate how far you are willing to go: For example, the more restrictive you are in terms of where you might be willing to move to, the fewer your opportunities.
6. For almost everyone, there are other very rewarding careers besides an academic one, and for some of these alternatives, having a PhD is useful. If you go for something else, this is not a failure.